# dd measurement question

Tags: linux, performance, dd

I am wrestling with some perceived performance issues on a 3-node HPE Apollo cluster running Linux.  (The cluster supports a backup  application.)  These are very $$ servers.  In our setup each node has 40 CPU's (2 sockets, 10 cores per socket with hyperthreading enabled).

Here is my simple test:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=256K count=10000
```

The command reports a 'thruput' of 1.5GB/s.  Running the exact same command on my lame HP desktop workstation (Ubuntu) gives 13.7GB/s, and running an another HPE G9 Linux server (not an Apollo) generates 17.8GB/s.  This dd command should be virtually all CPU (with a small bit of memory), and on an Apollo server I would have expected a quite stellar 'thruput' measurement for taking an endless stream of zeros and piping them into the bit bucket.  But 1.5GB/s??  That seems quite pathetic to me.  Am I crazy in thinking something is just not right with the Apollo?  What could possibly explain this differential in performance?

Comment: "command should be virtually all CPU (with a small bit of memory" is that the case? All this command does is take CPU-generated zeros, copy them to memory, and write them to a destination that discards them. Neither generation nor discarding would be time-consuming, but copying zeros to and from the RAM is where the bulk of them time would go. It's easy to check what's the bottleneck - tie it to a CPU core and check if that core gets 100% usage.

Comment: Same results with `taskset -c 0 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=256K count=100000` ?

Comment: Does each system have the same kernel version and the same dd?

Comment: Each of the Apollo nodes is identical in kernel version and any executables.  Tried the taskset command as suggested and that returned exact same results.  Looks like I will be opening support ticket to HPE to get some explanation.

Comment: Do the Apollo and non-Apollo systems have the same versions of dd?